# Restricted phpinfo.php file downloading rather than displaying in browser

Tags: php, magento, nginx, .htpasswd

I'm trying to set up my NGINX configuration file so that only users who have the `htpsasswd` can view *our-site.com/phpinfo.php* in their browser.

Within my `server block`, I defined a `location block` for this in my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` configuration file.

```
# PHP: phpinfo() access restrictions
location ~ ^\/phpinfo\.php$ {
     auth_basic "Restricted website - authorised access only";
     auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
}
```

When I go to *our-site.com/phpinfo.php* I am prompted for the password but when I enter it the file is downloaded rather than displaying the phpinfo in the browser.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Here is my full configuration file

```
server {
    # Listen on port 80 as well as post 443 for SSL connections.
    listen 80;
    #listen 443 default ssl;

    #server_name localhost;
    server_name www.our-domain.com;

    # Specify path to your SSL certificates.
   #ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certificates/yourcertificate.crt;
    #ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certificates/yourcertificate.key;

    # Path to the files in which you wish to
    # store your access and error logs.
    #access_log /path/to/your/logs/access_log;
    #error_log /path/to/your/logs/error_log;

    # If the site is accessed via mydomain.com
    # automatically redirect to www.magento.localhost.com.
    #if ($host = 'production' ) {
        #rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://www.production/$1permanent;
   #}

    root /var/www/production/;

    location / {
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
        auth_basic "Restricted website - authorised access only";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }

    # Denies access to specific directories no one
    # in particular needs access to anyways.
    location /app/ { deny all; }
    location /includes/ { deny all; }
    location /lib/ { deny all; }
    location /media/downloadable/ { deny all; }
    location /pkginfo/ { deny all; }
    location /report/config.xml { deny all; }
    location /var/ { deny all; } 

    # PHP: phpinfo() access restrictions
    location ~ ^\/phpinfo\.php$ {
         auth_basic "Restricted website - authorised access only";
         auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }

    location /admin {
         index index.html index.htm index.php;
         try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
         auth_basic "Restricted website - authorised access only";
         auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }


    # Deny all attempts to access hidden files
    # such as .htaccess, .htpasswd, etc...
    location ~ /\. {
         deny all;
         access_log off;
         log_not_found off;
    }

    # This redirect is added so to use Magentos
    # common front handler when handling incoming URLs.
    location @handler {
        rewrite / /index.php;
    }

    # Forward paths such as /js/index.php/x.js
    # to their relevant handler.
    location ~ .php/ {
        rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
    }

    ##
    # Rewrite for versioned CSS+JS via filemtime
    ##
    location ~* ^.+\.(css|js)$ {
        rewrite ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(css|js)$ $1.$3 last;
        expires 31536000s;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public";
    }
    ##
    # Aggressive caching for static files
    # If you alter static files often, please use 
    # add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    ##
    location ~* \.(asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|ogv|otf|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|svg|svgz|swf|tar|t?gz|tif|tiff|ttf|wav|webm|wma|woff|wri|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip)$ {
        expires 31536000s;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public";
    }

       # Handle the exectution of .php files.
    location ~ .php$ {
        if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite / /index.php last;
        }
        expires off;

        # --PHP5-FPM CONFIG START (keep fastcgi_param HTTPS OFF)--
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        ##fastcgi_param HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
        #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        # --PHP5-FPM CONFIG START--

        # --HHVM CONFIG START--
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler; 
        # --HHVM CONFIG END--

        fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
        fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
        include fastcgi_params;
   }
}
```

It a ubuntu box running a NGINX server with HHVM for a Magento app.

Comment: Show us the rest of your config, please.

Comment: @ceejayoz, just added it, thanks

Comment: `include` content of the `location ~ \.php$` also into the `location ~ ^\/phpinfo\.php$`

Answer (score 0):

Your `phpinfo.php` location block won't roll down to `location ~ .php$ {` when it's done - each location block is independent. You need to copy the various `fastcgi` etc. rules into it (or for easier maintenance, put them in an include).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  I changed it to `location ~ ^\/phpinfo\.php$ {include fastcgi_params;
         auth_basic "Restricted website - authorised access only";
         auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }
` but still having the same issue

Comment: @CreedBratton You need the whole thing - `fastcgi_pass`, `try_files`, etc. Without them, nothing tells the `phpinfo.php` block to pass off to PHP at all.